# "Initializing oneAPI environment" upon opening terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, intel, fortran

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

After I have installed oneAPI Base Toolkit and HPC toolkit, every time I open the terminal this oneAPI environment initialization massage appears.

```
:: initializing oneAPI environment ...
   BASH version = 5.0.17(1)-release
:: clck -- latest
:: intelpython -- latest
:: vtune -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: debugger -- latest
:: vpl -- latest
:: ippcp -- latest
:: dal -- latest
:: ccl -- latest
:: dpl -- latest
:: dpcpp-ct -- latest
:: dev-utilities -- latest
:: tbb -- latest
:: inspector -- latest
:: itac -- latest
:: mkl -- latest
:: dnnl -- latest
:: mpi -- latest
:: compiler -- latest
:: advisor -- latest
:: oneAPI environment initialized ::
```

Is there a way to make this long initialization message silent?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the line below in .bashrc

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```

initializes the oneAPI environment. When I deleted this command line, the problem solved and oneAPI continue to operate afterwards.